# setTimeout in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, delay

Strange issue here, I don't see why it isn't working. But basically the alert is fire as soon as I press the button, there is no 5 second delay at all!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Page</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function testing() {
    var delay = 5000;
    setTimeout(alert("5 seconds later..."),delay);  
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Run Function" onClick="testing()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function testing() {
    var delay = 5000;
    setTimeout(function(){alert("5 seconds later...");},delay);  
}
```

Need to wrap it in a function so the alert is not immediately executed.

[Check out the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) for more information regarding how to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 5):

The setTimeout function is used as follows:

```
setTimeout(<function>, <delay>);
```

The first parameter is a function.  What you're doing is giving it the value of alert(..);

Change it to:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("5 seconds later..."); }, delay);
```